# assign value to a single dataframe in a list of dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created a list of 2 dataframes

```
df = [pd.DataFrame(0, columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'], index = range(0, 5))] * 2

df[0]['a'][1] = 55
```

Current output:

```
[    a  b  c
 0   0  0  0
 1  55  0  0
 2   0  0  0
 3   0  0  0
 4   0  0  0,     a  b  c
 0   0  0  0
 1  55  0  0
 2   0  0  0
 3   0  0  0
 4   0  0  0]
```

Expected output:

```
[    a  b  c
 0   0  0  0
 1  55  0  0
 2   0  0  0
 3   0  0  0
 4   0  0  0,     a  b  c
 0   0  0  0
 1   0  0  0
 2   0  0  0
 3   0  0  0
 4   0  0  0]
```

I would expect this code snippet to assign a value of 1 to the first df, col a and index 1. However it assigns values to both dataframes.

I am not sure if the issue arises because I created the list by multiplying a df by 2, which is resulting in applying the result to all the dfs.

Is there a way to create a list of multiple dfs and have result attached to only one df based on index.

Thanks

Comment: When you multiply a list like that you're not making more copies, you're making duplicate refrences to the same object. So they all point to the same thing it's just showing it 2x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension instead:

```
df = [pd.DataFrame(0, columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'], index = range(0, 5)) for _ in range(2)]

df[0]['a'][1] = 55

#
[    a  b  c
0   0  0  0
1  55  0  0
2   0  0  0
3   0  0  0
4   0  0  0,    a  b  c
0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0
2  0  0  0
3  0  0  0
4  0  0  0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You created a shallow copy. Try this:

```
df = [pd.DataFrame(0, columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'], index = range(0, 5)) for _ in range(2)]
```